# Bi-directional NHibernate mapping by code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

Just to be clear - this question is not about Fluent NHibernate.

I have a `Parent` and `Child` classes, with a one-to-many relationship between them.

The code is shortened for readability.

```
public class Child
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}

public class Parent
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Child> Children;
}

public ChildMapping()
{
    Table("Children");

    Id(p => p.Id, m => {
        m.Column("Id");
        m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
    });

    Property(p => p.Name, m => {
        m.Column("Name");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });
}

public ParentMapping()
{
    Table("Parents");

    Id(p => p.Id, m => {
        m.Column("Id");
        m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
    });

    Property(p => p.Name, m => {
        m.Column("Name");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });

    Set(p => p.Children, m => {
        m.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        m.Key(k => {
            k.Column("ParentId");
            k.NotNullable(true);
        });
    }, a => a.OneToMany());
}
```

The `Child` class needs a `Parent` property on it.
The `Parent` needs to control the relationship (I can't set the `Inverse` to `true` on the `Parent`'s end).

How should the `Parent` and `Child` mapping look like?

Comment: you may find this series of blog posts useful; it's practically the only documentation I could find of mapping-by-code. http://notherdev.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html

Comment: Thank you. It's also the only documentation I've found, but it didn't help me much. If I manage to figure this out, I'll answer the question myself :)

Comment: well, the parent mapping seems ok, don't you just need a `many-to-one` on the child end and that's it?

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following items:

Child class: a field _parent, a constructor
Parent class: AddChild method
Child mapping: manytoone for parent property
Parent mapping: inverse(true) to make parent handler of the children

Complete code:

```
public class Child
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    Parent _parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
   {
     _parent = parent;
   }
}

public class Parent
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Child> Children;

    public virtual Child AddChild()
    {
       Child newChild = new Child(this); //link parent to child via constructor
       Children.Add(newChild); //add child to parent's collection
       return newChild; //return child for direct usage
    }
}

public ChildMapping()
{
    Table("Children");

    Id(p => p.Id, m => {
        m.Column("Id");
        m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
    });

    Property(p => p.Name, m => {
        m.Column("Name");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });

    ManyToOne(x => x.Parent, map => {
         map.Column("Id"); /* id of the parent table */
         map.Access(Accessor.Field);
         map.NotNullable(true);
         map.Class(typeof(Parent));
        });    
}

public ParentMapping()
{
    Table("Parents");

    Id(p => p.Id, m => {
        m.Column("Id");
        m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
    });

    Property(p => p.Name, m => {
        m.Column("Name");
        m.NotNullable(true);
    });

    Set(p => p.Children, m => {
        m.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        m.Key(k => {
            k.Column("Id"); /* id of the child table */
            k.NotNullable(true);
            k.Inverse(true); /* makes the parent handle it's childlist */
        });
    }, a => a.OneToMany());
}
```

that should work.